# Multiple Jenkins on same tomcat server in linux

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, tomcat8

I want to set up 2 jenkins on same tomcat server -8.5.34 in linux.
I Downloaded https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war and placed in webapps folders of tomcat as jen-dev and jen-qa

However, for both Jenkins, I want to use different Jenkins home locations:

```
JENKINS1_HOME : /opt/jen-dev             JENKINS2_HOME : /opt/jen-qa
```

If I try setting below variable in shell and start tomcat using bin/startup.sh, jen-dev is working fine as http://jenkins.dev.com/jen-dev.

```
export JENKINS_HOME="/opt/jen-dev"
```

How can I customize this installation to include second Jenkins home and run on same server as http://jenkins.dev.com/jen-qa?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to set the `JENKINS_HOME` parameter (cf. [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/administering+jenkins)):

- as a **system** environment variable,
- as a **system** property,
- as a **JNDI** environment entry.

The first two options will apply to the entire Tomcat server, so you need to use JNDI. Create a descriptor file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/jen-dev.xml` with content:

```xml
<Context>
    <Environment type="java.lang.String" override="false"
                 name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/opt/jen-dev" />
</Context>
```

and define a similar descriptor for the other Jenkins instance.