# Get values of individual context.xml in Jersey's ResourceConfig?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I have a pretty simple servlet setup with

1. Jersey
2. no `web.xml`
3. Tomcat 9
4. Maven for creating the *.war* and handling dependencies

Now I need to deploy a test and a production version of the servlet on the server and I a trying to use the *individual context.xml* file for each environment. A [quote from the do](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)cs

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:

> In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's META-INF directory.

All this also sounds easy [here](https://medium.com/byteagenten/simple-application-configuration-with-tomcat-5cad0a551ba6):

```
To give an example: if we wanted to deploy three installations of an application for test, stage and production, we would create three context.xml files:

tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost/test.xml
tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost/stage.xmltomcat/conf/catalina/localhost/prod.xml

And then deploy the same .war file three times as:

tomcat/webapps/test.war
tomcat/webapps/stage.war
tomcat/webapps/prod.war

And each installation would pick up its specific configuration automatically.
```

You can also [read this documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_are_.3CContext.3E_elements_added_to_server.xml_when_Dynamic_Web_Projects_are_added_to_the_Tomcat_server.3F):

> For Tomcat 5.0.x and later, WTP 2.0.x and later offers the opportunity to write the contexts to separate XML files in the proper folder (typically conf/Catalina/localhost) according to the requirements of that particular version. This behavior is enabled by checking the Publish module contexts to separate XML files option in the Server Options section of the Tomcat server editor. Note that only contexts for added projects will be written to separate XML files. Manually added contexts in server.xml will remain there.

There are [several instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227888/i-want-to-read-the-parameters-of-tomcat-context-xml), how to retrieve a value from the *context.xml*. **For example**:

```
<Environment name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated" type="java.lang.String" />
```

Can be used by

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
Context xmlNode = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
String companyName = (String) xmlNode.lookup("companyName");
```

#### But this was listed for a Spring setup, how can this be done in a Jersey ResourceConfig based application/servlet?

For example:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyMain extends ResourceConfig {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMain.class);

    public MyMain() {

    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        String myEnv = (String) envCtx.lookup("my-env");
        this.logger.debug("Env: {}", myEnv);
    } ...
```

is running into `NamedExceptions`: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [my-env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [my-env].`

#### Is there any way to get the context configuration with Jersey, or do I need to use a different approach?

I also have no clue, how to debug the `InitialContext`. So the file is there and it is read by Tomcat, but I don't know how I can access it in the application. **Do I need to use [`ServletContext.getInitParameter()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) instead - and how?**

### Update

My Eclipse setup seems to be the problem, because the published *xml* file is not the original, individual *context.xml* in my `/Catalina/localhost` folder. **Is there any way to make sure that the original file is published in the Eclipse-Tomcat server**?

"Publish module contexts to separate XML files" is checked. What is *Update context paths?* in publishing options (no effect visible, though)?

Here is the [image: Eclipse server config]:

Comment: JNDI lookup is not specific to Spring, but check your configuration details. The context files should be in `conf/Catalina/localhost` with a capital `C` (unless you change the engine's name). If everything is done right you'll have `Deploying deployment descriptor...` in the logs instead of `Deploying web application...`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz This works, Tomcat says: `INFO: Deploying deployment descriptor [/home/myname/work/some-folder/eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-servlet.xml]`. So I think I am using `InitialContext` the wrong way or `ServletContext` is the right way? Do I need to *inject* it into the main class?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Or it is a problem with my Eclipse setup.

Comment: Eclipse puts the contexts directly into `server.xml` (unless _"Publish module contexts to separate XML files"_ is checked) and I find it a little bit buggy. Better check what did Eclipse actually publish in `org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0`. In Eclipse I usually put everything in the global `context.xml` file (in the Servers project).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz "Publish module contexts to separate XML files" is checked and the xml file is indeed at the right place (like the Tomcat logs are saying). **Oh wow, but the file is not the original one.** It is an artificial one `<Context docBase="my-servlet" path="/my-servlet" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:my-servlet"/>`. Do you mean this by *buggy*? There is no way to make sure that the original file in my Tomcat.../Catalina/localhost folder is loaded?

Comment: Disable the _"...to separate XML files"_ option and define your JNDI environment directly in the `<Context docBase="my-servlet">` element of the `server.xml` file that Eclipse created for you in the `Servers` project. BTW: you might consider taking your parameters from multiple sources (see e.g. what [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) or [Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921501/11748454) do). Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67737589/11748454).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks, this works! I just hope that the setup [with individual `.xml` files](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) works for the actual Tomcat on our production server. Do you know whether I need to configure the production Tomcat in a certain way for using this approach?

Comment: Just don't configure the `<Context>` elements in `server.xml` (it is highly discouraged). If you have `webapps/<app-name>.war` and `conf/Catalina/localhost/<app-name>.xml` Tomcat will automatically detect that it is the same application.